# Parsing a CSV file into multiple SQL tables. Pivoting column names to row variables with a new id

Tags: sql, csv

I have multiple CVS files that I need to add into my database. I want to add the CVS data into multiple SQL tables and also take the column names and parse as variables in the same column and give them separate ids.

The CVS files have similar setup:

| CustomerID | apple | orange | banana | mango |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 4 | 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 5 | 6 | 8. | 9. |
| 3 | 7 | 2 | 3 | 1 |

and get the following tables:

Fruits

| ID | Fruit_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple |
| 2 | orange. |
| 3 | banana. |
| 4 | mango |

Receipt

| ID. | CustomerID | FruitID | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1. | 1. | 30. |
| 2 | 1. | 2. | 4. |
| 3 | 1. | 3. | 2. |
| 4 | 1. | 4. | 7 |
| 5 | 2. | 1 | 5. |
| 6 | 2. | 2. | 6. |
| 7 | 2. | 3. | 8. |
| 8 | 2. | 4. | 9. |

etc.

I don't know where to start. If I should add the csv files to sql temp table and then seperate or iterate directly into the tables in the database.

I'm probably complicating the thought process in my head so all ideas are helpful.

Comment: *I don't know where to start* ... start with [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451) to find *any* implementation that works for you, then [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a *specific* question regarding your coding attempt. Since there are numerous ways to reshape and append delimited data, this question is too broad. Also, tag your DBMS (SQL Server, Postgres, etc.) with your [mcve].

Comment: Your first step is to import, as-is into staging tables. Then write SQL queries to transform. Can you confirm whether the input file has a fixed number of columns? What happens when a new fruit is sold?